# One-word expression for 'making a slope gentler'

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, expressions

I cannot come up with a one-word expression for 'making a slope gentler' and the opposite expression also (making a slope steeper). For example, it may be less redundant to express '**A**ing a slope', if there is a verb **A** to indicate making it gentler. Could anyone recommend some expressions?

Comment: I think this is a related post (but not a duplicate): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21090/what-is-the-opposite-of-steep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Levelling**

Levelling is a word used to make something more level.

To use it in some sentences close to your question:

> The slope was too steep so I levelled it off a bit.
>
> Adrian thought the slop was too steep so he's spending the afternoon levelling it off.

The opposite could be **raising**.

It doesn't work perfectly and when I try saying it out loud I'd go for a longer form but this word would achieve your goal.

Answer (score 4):

There is the verb [to grade](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grading):

> To level or smooth to a desired or horizontal gradient:
>   *Bulldozers graded the road.*

Usually it has to do with making the ground slope at the correct amount of steepness, but it can be used for other things. For example:

> Without background activity (dashed line), the probability was all-or-none, reflecting the threshold for action potentials. With background activity (continuous line), **the response curve was graded** and there was a non-null response for subthreshold inputs (<0.2 mS/cm2).

<sup>Source: [FLUCTUATING SYNAPTIC CONDUCTANCES RECREATE *IN VIVO*-LIKE ACTIVITY IN NEOCORTICAL NEURONS](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3320220/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can also **[ease](https://books.google.com/books?id=yVcOk8XsyEkC&pg=PA462&dq=%22ease+the+slope%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE84mwscrWAhUFOiYKHSaECDYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22ease%20the%20slope%22&f=false)** a slope.

The slope of the driveway is too steep. It needs to be **eased** somewhat. We would like it to be more gradual.